# IndexError: tuple index out of range (np.shape, reshape)

Tags: python, numpy

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data['High'].values.reshape(-1,1))

prediction_days=100

x_train=[]
y_train=[]

for i in range(prediction_days, len(scaled_data)):
    x_train.append(scaled_data[prediction_days-i:,0])
    y_train.append(scaled_data[i,0])


x_train,y_train= np.array(x_train),np.array(y_train)

x_train=np.reshape(x_train,(x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1))
```

```py
File "C:\Users\Desktop\untitled0.py", line 37, in <module>
    x_train=np.reshape(x_train,(x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1))

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is `x_train.shape`?  Looks like `x_train` is a 1d array.  Look at the arrays in the problem line.  You could even be nice, and let us look at them!.